# How do I splice an item from a variable?

Tags: splice

I feel like this should be so easy, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Print Bill's salary from the my_list object shown below.

```
my_list = [{'Tom': 20000, 'Bill': 12000}, ['car', 'laptop', 'TV']]
```

I entered:

```
print(my_list[23:28])
```

and it just returns `[]`

I am a newbie so be kind, please. Thanks all!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the tag of the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no elements between array index 23 and 28. I tried using [0:2] instead and I got the original array.

EDIT: SHORT WARNING: suppose you want to input 5 and 9 into the splice machine. It will return a array with array index:

```
5 6 7 8
```

9 will not be included.
To pull bill’s salary, you would do

```
my_list[0]['Bill']
```

Splicing is unnessary.

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are going out of the index, as 23 and 28 are not on the list.
Try:

```
my_list = [{'Tom': 20000, 'Bill': 12000}, ['car', 'laptop', 'TV']]

print(my_list[1:2])
```

Also, as a side note, please consider using code blocks to write code

Comment: Thank you. So, where would I start counting the integers from zero to pull Bill's salary from the variable.